# How to convert all tables from FGDB into CSV using OGR2OGR?

Tags: convert, ogr2ogr, table

I am trying to convert tables in FGDB to CSV formats.
I have 40 or more tables though by the way.

This is the code that i used and it seemed to work fine

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f csv "D:\NGII_Emap\-al.csv" "D:\NGII_Emap\input_table.gdb"
```

however, when I see the results only the first file's name is -al.csv and the other csv files are as same as the FGDB tables.

[image]
[image]

I want all the output names as same as in the FGDB tables

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your aim? Is it to create just one csv file that is named -al.csv and that holds all the data from all tables? Do all your tables have exactly same attribute schema?

Comment: @user30184 I am trying to convert feature table in FGDB to CSVs and also want to keep the FGDB table names same as output csv files. and i'd like to create separate tables like the input. -al means "for all layers" according to ogr2ogr cookbook. for this input, it has same attribute schema. but i want this code to be more universal.

Comment: CSV driver is a bit special and it handles directories as data stores which  can contain many layers. Try `ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f csv "D:\NGII_Emap\" "D:\NGII_Emap\input_table.gdb"`

Comment: @user30184 oh! although it does create a new folder and save the tables in it. it just works perfect. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f csv "D:\NGII_Emap\" "D:\NGII_Emap\input_table.gdb"
```

it does create the NGII_Emap folder.
so if you have NGII_Emap folder already, you'd better change the name

Comment: It is even documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html:  `The driver supports creating new databases (as a directory of .csv files), adding new .csv files to an existing directory or .csv files or appending features to an existing .csv table.`