# Reading GDB file with GeoPandas throws MemoryError

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, geopandas, fiona

I have a gdb file that's 32GB and I'm tasked with extracting the attribute values from each of the layers and converting them to CSV for analysis. Here's my code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona as fiona

dataset_path = '...' # for example purposes left out the exact path

layers = fiona.listlayers(dataset_path)
for layername in layers:
    # according to docs settin ignore_geometry=True loads gpd file to pandas dataframe
    geodata = gpd.read_file(dataset_path, driver='fileGDB', layer=layername, ignore_geometry=True)
    geodata.to_csv(project_path + f'{layername}.csv')
```

This code works but there are some layers that are very large (~5000 columns x 40'000 rows) and for those, it throws `MemoryError` and everything on my computer crashes because the PC has ran out of RAM.

Is there anything I can do to optimize this besides trying to acquire a more powerful computer? (I have 16GB of RAM).

- I already tried to load the file into QGIS and export it from there, but it throws a similar error and crashes anyway.

Comment: As there isn't any reason to read more than one feature at a time for this purpose, I suggest you try using a feature stream approach.

Comment: You can specify only a subset of rows with `rows` keyword in `read_file` - https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file

Comment: Maybe ogr2ogr is more memory efficient. Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-fgdb-into-csv-using-ogr2ogr

Comment: It seems that the `rows` parameter has not effect on `gpd.read_file` for a `.gdb` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success.

- I used the `ignore_fields` argument in `read_file` to drop unnecessary columns reducing the size of the import. It's not a quick solution, but at least it does not cause a memory error.
- I also tried the `rows` method. According to documentation, you can provide a `slice()` object meaning that looping through the dataset and reading it bit by bit was not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `rows` parameter for `geopandas.read_file(file_path, rows=10)` was not working for me. There were no warnings or error messages when using `rows`, but the entire dataframe was being loaded instead of the subset.

It took me a while to figure out that the `rows` parameter was added in geopandas=0.7, and I was running geopandas=0.6.1. I had installed geopandas with `conda install geopandas` in a Python=3.8 environment containing default Anaconda packages. I had issues trying to upgrade geopandas so instead I created a new environment from scratch but this time installing geopandas with `conda install geopandas=0.9.0`. This resolved the `rows` parameter issue for me.